# Installing Perl Modules with XAMPP and Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, xampp, cpan

I have been looking everywhere but I seem to be failing to get it.
I want to install a perl module on my current XAMPP setup with Ubuntu .
I have looked and tried everywhere and these two seemed promising.

http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=135509

command:  /opt/lampp/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'install MIME::Lite'

http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html

command:  cpanm MIME::Lite

Both commands installed the module just fine but when I use it, it gives me a server error that states that the module MIME::Lite is not found. Below is the error message.

Error message:
Can't locate MIME/Lite.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /root/perl5/lib/perl5/i686-linux /root/perl5/lib/perl5 /opt/lampp/lib/perl5/5.10.1/i686-linux /opt/lampp/lib/perl5/5.10.1 /opt/lampp/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/i686-linux /opt/lampp/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1 . /opt/lampp) at /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/unlibolt/login/homepage.pl line 8. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/unlibolt/login/homepage.pl line 8. ,

Please help.

I also would like to add that I did the same command (/opt/lampp/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBI') and it installed DBI properly and for some reason doesn't when I try to install MIME::Lite and JSON.

Comment: what says your CPAN Config?

Comment: I apologize for my newbness but how do I access the cpan config?

Comment: i have no idea about the path in your system... but you need to call something like `/opt/lampp/bin/cpan` and then type inside the cpan shell  `o conf`.

Comment: Here we go. That was pretty accurate actually. So what do I need to be looking at with the conf file? Also I installed DBI just fine before. Strange that doing the same command wouldn't install MIME::Lite and JSON properly.


cpan[1]> o conf                                                                                                                                                                 
$CPAN::Config options from '/root/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm':

Comment: hmm... maybe your shebang line is incorrect. try to write `#!/opt/lampp/bin/perl`.

Comment: My shebang line is exactly like that already. Strange that it behaves like this since I did this for the perl module DBI and it works but it doesn't work for MIME::Lite :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28706/discussion-between-tofu-and-paulchenkiller)